# Lifespan of a static member variable declared and initialized in a dynamically loaded DLL

Tags: c++, dll, static, dynamic-loading

Please consider the following code example. My question is: where is Foo::bar stored in memory? Is it stored in the static storage of the program that main.cpp is compiled into? If so, what happens when myDll.so is unloaded?

```
//myDll.hpp

//class definitions
class Bar
{
  public:
    Bar() = default;
};

class Foo
{
  public:
    static Bar bar;
};

//declaring free function to be exported
extern "C" Bar* getBar();
```

---

```
//myDll.cpp
#include "myDll.hpp"

//initializing static member variable
Bar Foo::bar;

//definition of exported function
Bar* getBar()
{
  return &(Foo::bar);  
}
```

---

Suppose that myDll.cpp is made into myDll.so like such:
`g++ -shared -fPIC -o myDll.so myDll.cpp`, and it is dynamically loaded like such:

```
//main.cpp
void* handle = dlopen( "/path/to/dll/myDll.so", RTLD_NOW);
// do stuff with handle...
dlclose( handle );
```

What happens when dlclose() is called? Does Foo::bar go out of scope immediately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. `Foo::bar` exists in the static storage section (the ".data" segment) of `myDll.so` which will be un-mapped after `dlclose`.

I can think of two exceptions:

- The C library isn't required to unload the DLL. Some C libraries (for example, [musl](https://wiki.musl-libc.org/functional-differences-from-glibc.html)) explicitly document that they no-op `dlclose()`
- dlopen/dlclose are reference counted. If you've called `dlopen` on this same library twice, the first call to `dlopen` will not unload the library.

Comment: You are saying that ``myDll.so`` and the main program (the program that ``main.cpp`` is compiled into) have separate static storage sections, right? If so, I wonder if they also have separate stacks and heaps?

Comment: @megamonium Stacks belong to threads, not to .so's or DLLs or EXEs. The C runtime can have a separate memory heap in the .so, depending on how the .so was linked.

Comment: That's correct, each library will have it's own section for static variables. The "stack" (originally set up by the kernel) and "heap" (expanded with brk()) are not shared however. As an experiment, you can run pmap on the PID before the dlopen, before the dlclose, and after the dlclose. You'll see the "read/not execute" mapping be created for the dll, then removed after dlclose. This is the address where the variable is located